# WiFi File Transfer Windows-7 and Vista

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, file-transfer, homegroup

I've been using Windows-7 homegroup between my netbook and laptop; I've grown quite fond of it. My roommate is running windows Vista, so his computer lacks this feature. We'd really like to be able to have a common folder between our two computers. Is there any third party software that can do a similar trick?

Comment: Depends on what you've done so far, please detail. If it's general file sharing, it's probably Samba, so try this http://www.builderau.com.au/blogs/codemonkeybusiness/viewblogpost.htm?p=339270746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this article :

[How do I make Windows 7 HomeGroup content accessible to Vista and XP?](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/how-do-i-make-windows-7-homegroup-content-accessible-to-vista-and-xp/1910)

Comment: Homegroups is just a very simplified face on top of Windows file sharing.

Answer (score 0):

What Microsoft has to say about Netorking different versions of Windows on home computers

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows